# Scrapy only processes first 10 requests in iterable

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I have a crawler that starts from a sitemap, grabs (a couple) 100 unique urls, and then does further processing on those 100 pages. However, I only get callbacks on the first 10 urls. The spider logs seem to only call HTTP GETs on the first 10 urls.

```
class MySpider(scrapy.spider.BaseSpider):

    # settings ... 

    def parse(self, response):
        urls = [...]
        for url in urls:
            request = scrapy.http.Request(url, callback=self.parse_part2)
            print url
            yield request

    def parse_part2(self, response):
        print response.url
        # do more parsing here
```

I've considered these options:

1. scrambling the list
2. setting download delays (pretty sure I'm not getting rate limited)
3. dont_filter=True arg
4. returning an array of requests instead of yielding
5. disabling parallel requests

Is there some mysterious max_branching_factor flag I am not aware of or something?

---

### edit : logs, perfectly normal.

```
2015-02-11 02:05:12-0800 [mysite] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET url1>
yay callback!
2015-02-11 02:05:12-0800 [mysite] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET url2>
2015-02-11 02:05:12-0800 [mysite] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET url3> 
2015-02-11 02:05:12-0800 [mysite] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET url4> 
2015-02-11 02:05:12-0800 [mysite] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET url5> 
2015-02-11 02:05:12-0800 [mysite] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET url6> 
yay callback!
yay callback!
yay callback!
yay callback!
yay callback!
2015-02-11 02:05:12-0800 [mysite] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET url7> 
yay callback!
2015-02-11 02:05:13-0800 [mysite] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET url8> 
yay callback!
2015-02-11 02:05:13-0800 [mysite] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET url9> 
yay callback!
2015-02-11 02:05:13-0800 [mysite] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET url10> 
yay callback!
2015-02-11 02:05:13-0800 [mysite] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2015-02-11 02:05:13-0800 [mysite] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
  {'downloader/request_bytes': 4590,
   'downloader/request_count': 11,
   'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 11,
   'downloader/response_bytes': 638496,
   'downloader/response_count': 11,
   'downloader/response_status_count/200': 11,
   'finish_reason': 'finished',
   'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 11, 10, 5, 13, 260322),
   'log_count/DEBUG': 17,
   'log_count/INFO': 3,
   'request_depth_max': 1,
   'response_received_count': 11,
   'scheduler/dequeued': 11,
   'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 11,
   'scheduler/enqueued': 11,
   'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 11,
   'start_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 11, 10, 5, 12, 492811)}
2015-02-11 02:05:13-0800 [mysite] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: Are the rest of urls are in an invalid format?

Comment: nope, if I set urls=reversed(urls) or urls = urls[10:] I still get exactly 10 callbacks.

Comment: A question about your configuration. What are the values of DEPTH_LIMIT ? Why you are not using follow=True in rule ?

Comment: DEPTH_LIMIT defaults to 0 right? which means no cap. Also follow=false because I have a callback which will manually process the links that I want to scrape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so I found this attribute in one of my settings files

```
max_requests / MAX_REQUESTS = 10
```

which is responsible for the spider quitting early (oops)

Answer (score 0):

try to set LOG_LEVEL to debug you will see more logs.

and if you do so.please paste them on

Comment: The LOG_LEVEL is debug by default and I didn't find anything suspicious from it.